# Very Basic Mac Terminal Issue

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm brand new to using Mac Terminal and I can't seem to figure out what's going on when I try to navigate directories. I have experience in MS-DOS (from many many years ago...but I still get the basic idea) and it's not working the way I'd like it to.

I'm trying to navigate to any directory and it's not allowing me to. If I type:

cd/Applications

It's giving me the error:

```
-bash: cd/Applications: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to navigate to it from the default directory and I also tried to navigate to it after typing:

```
sudo -s
```

Which I read was how to get to the absolute root directory. I know this is impossibly basic but can someone point me in the right direction on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `cd <directory_name>` (e.g. `cd Desktop`). Your user home directory will be at `cd ~/`

Comment: What do you mean by this exactly? Is cd/Applications not appropriate syntax?

Comment: That syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space between the command name, "cd", and each of its arguments, in this case directory name "/Applications". So:

```
cd /Applications
```

Comment: Wow, there it is! Thanks, I can accept your answer in 12 minutes and I will do that. Thanks!

Comment: You're more than welcome!